# Retrofit2 custom Converter to encrypt request,@Field used but convert stringConverter not work

Tags: encryption, request, converters, retrofit2

I am so confused,when i use Retrofit2（retrofit version 2.1.0 @） to encrypt my request ,api like this

```
 public interface API {
       @FormUrlEncoded
       @POST("login.do?os=" + ConstantValue.OS + "&version=" + ConstantValue.VERSION)
       Observable<LoginInfo> login(@Field("cmd") String params);
  }
```

my Coustom Converter main code

```
  @Override
  public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type,    Annotation[] annotations,
  Retrofit retrofit) {
     TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
     return new DecryptResponseBodyConverter<>(gson, adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type,
   Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
     TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
     return new EncryptRequestBodyConverter<>(gson, adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[]     annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
     TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
     return new EncryptRequestStringConverter<>(gson,adapter);
  }
```

the method stringConverter of my custom Converter do not work. retrofit2.BuildInConvert$StringConverter first execute before mine..

help~help~

Answer (score 0):

i found the default BuildInConverters,its stringConverter will intercept the request which type is String.

```
    @Override public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (type == String.class) {
            return StringConverter.INSTANCE;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

so i change the type of the parameter,like this

```
public interface API {
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("login.do?os=" + ConstantValue.OS + "&version=" + ConstantValue.VERSION)
   Observable<LoginInfo> login(@Field("cmd") JsonObject params);
```

}

then it work.